# SQL - How to get columns from row values in the same column (SQL Server 2016)

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need to derive columns from the row values of one column.

Here's the row data.

```
CustomerID  Activity    Date
10001       Active      2018-06-21
10001       Inactive    2018-06-25
10001       Active      2018-08-22
10001       Inactive    2018-10-06
```

And here's the output that I am trying to get to:

```
CustomerID  ActiveDate      InactiveDate
10001       2018-06-21      2018-06-25
10001       2018-08-22      2018-10-06
```

Please help! Thanks!

Comment: please provide a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Are you certain that for every "active" there is an associated "inactive" that is the row that immediately follows (based on date)? Don't assume, go look. And don't just look at the first set of rows that you see in the results window of a SSMS query (or the results of the "select rows" menu).

Answer (score 1):

You can try to make row number in subquery `group by CustomerID,Activity`, then do condition aggregate function.

```
SELECT CustomerID,
       MAX(CASE WHEN Activity = 'Active' THEN Date END) ActiveDate,
       MAX(CASE WHEN Activity = 'Inactive' THEN Date END) InactiveDate
FROM (
    SELECT *,ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY CustomerID,Activity ORDER BY Date ) rn
    FROM T
)t1
group by CustomerID,rn
```

[sqlfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=94d758fb9492f7522a40a0efad40ac70)

Comment: I dont see any need for row number here.

Comment: if didn't make row number the pivot will get only one row? or Could you post your another solution? I am looking forward :)

Comment: Did you mean this? https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=893c3ced7b1add46a3a85c7d7bae57ed

Comment: Ah sorry just realised I missed that it was the same Customerid throughout. Thought they were 2 different customers

Comment: Yep the problem is sample data have same `Customerid`, therefore I need to create a row number for it :)

Answer (score 0):

You logic is a little unclear.  If you want the next "inactive" date:

```
select CustomerID, date as active_date, inactive_date
from (select t.*,
             min(case when activity = 'Inactive' then date end) over (partition by CustomerID order by date desc) as inactive_date
      from t
     ) t
where activity = 'Active';
```